# Counting of objects in linked list

Tags: c

I have a linked list and I need to count only some of records according some criteria. I have got this code.

```
   int count_records() {
    int number = 0;
    RECORD *re;
    char criteria[20];

    for (re = first; re != NULL; re = re->next) {
        criteria = (re->criteria);
        if(criteria=="something")
        number++;
    }

    return number; }
```

Structure of linked list is this:

```
typedef struct record {
    char criteria[20];
    struct record *next;
} RECORD;
```

Problem is that it gives me this error on line **criteria = (re->criteria);** *Error: Invalid array assignment*

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: The only idea worth mentioning is to replace all of the `char[]` with `std::string`.  C-style arrays are really second class citizens, and don't have value semantics.

Comment: Alternatively use `!strcmp(criteria,"something")`

Comment: @Edward `strcmp` doesn't return a `bool`, but an `int`, so using `!` on it is a bit obfuscating.  The idiom here would be `strcmp( criteria, "something" ) == 0`.  (Except, of course, the real idiom would be to use `std::string`, and forget about all of these complications.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: the form I wrote is an ancient and common idiom, but yes, `std::string` would be much better if the problem doesn't prohibit it for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You have arrays of char´s. To copy or compare an array, you´ll need to copy/compare each element separately instead of using = and == on the whole array in one go.
And instead of making a loop, you can use strcpy and strcmp in this case:

```
strcpy(criteria, re->criteria);
if(!strcmp(criteria, "something"))
```

By the way, this is more C than C++. If you want a C++-like solution, see std::string (then you can  work with = and == too)

Comment: @DavidHolada did you get an answer? check the answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `memcpy` in order to copy arrays, but be careful using memcpy when exposed on a public interface. I think there was a [recent security issue involving this...](http://heartbleed.com)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you can't copy arrays using `=`. Neither can you compare them using `==`. They are quite strange, unfriendly things, which need a certain amount of care to use.

If you want to use arrays, you can use the C library to compare them:

```
if (std::strcmp(re->criteria, "something") == 0)
```

Since this is C++, you might prefer to use `std::string` to represent strings; then it's just

```
if (re->criteria == "something")
```

and you can copy it with `=` if you need to (although you don't need to here).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy a `char` array into another, you need to use [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy). For example:

```
// will copy from array1 to array2
strcpy(array2, array1);
```

You can't directly do `array1 = array2`. Because in this case you would manipulate the adresses (`char *`) of the arrays and not their values.

---

In addition, in order to compare a `char` array to another, use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) instead:

```
if(strcmp(criteria, "something") == 0)
```

---

**P.S.:** Since you're using C++, [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) is your friend, which you can do assignment using `=` and comparison using `==`.

Comment: `strncpy` is very dangerous, since it can leave the destination without it's terminating `'\0'`.  Most places I've been (back when I was working in C) banned it.

Comment: @JamesKanze Replaced it by `strcpy`. Thanks.

Comment: Use of `strcpy()` assumes that the contents of the array is a null-terminated string.  It's not clear from the question if this is indeed the case, although the comparison with a null-terminated string later would seem to imply this.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you can and should use `std::string` for handling strings. You can find the reference ([here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)).

Just define `criteria` as `std::string criteria;` instead of `char criteria[20];`.

Don't forget to add `#include <string>` to the include section.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may wish to pass in the criterion to your `count_records()` function.  I'd render it like this:

```
int count_records(RECORD *first, const char *criterion) {
    int count = 0;
    RECORD *re;

    for (re = first; re != NULL; re = re->next) {
        /* add to count if the strings match */
        if(!strcmp(criterion, re->criteria))
            count++;
    }
    return count; 
}
```

Note that it also doesn't rely on `first` being a global variable which makes the code more reliable and easier to understand.

Answer (score -1):

Dealing with strings in C is a royal pain when you are starting out with the language. You can checkout [an online tutorial](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/courses/spring05/V22.0201-001/c_tutorial/classes/String.html) to get you started.

In the mean time, you can change your code to:

```
for (re = first; re != NULL; re = re->next) {
  if (strcmp(re->criteria, "something) == 0)
    number++;
}
```

You don't need to copy `re->criteria` to a local variable.